# Is there any way to recover unsaved annotations in Okular after system crash

Tags: kde, pdf, okular

Other popular PDF software such as Adobe Reader or Skim (on OS X) offer a functionality to restore your annotations after a system crash even if you haven't saved the file manually yet. Does Okular offer such a functionality, and if so, how can I use it?

I'm not sure if I understood the way Okular works correctly, but I usually use "Save As" to save the annotated PDF over the original PDF. I noticed that Okular also saves annotations separately in `~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`, however I can see multiple xml files about the same pdf file, and I'm not sure what they mean or how I can use them. (e.g.:

```
105718.03 Example.pdf.xml
183148.03 Example.pdf.xml
195752.03 Example.pdf.xml
315457.03 Example.pdf.xml
317056.03 Example.pdf.xml
354289.03 Example.pdf.xml
355255.03 Example.pdf.xml
```